# Custom Principal gets overridden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My custom principal gets overridden before executing controller action but I don't know where. I set the principal like this:

```
public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        if(HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}
```

As you see, I tried several ways to set the principal. However when the method `SendAsync` executes, principal gets overridden. I checked current thread id just before that line and in my action method. ID's are the same. How can I set the principal in a proper way?

Note: It is hosted in IIS

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. In `WebApiConfig` class there is a filter automatically added.

`config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));`

I decompiled `HostAuthenticationFilter` and there is a method which overrides it. Decompiled code:

```
public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(OwinResources.HttpAuthenticationContext_RequestMustNotBeNull);
    }
    IAuthenticationManager authenticationManagerOrThrow = GetAuthenticationManagerOrThrow(request);
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    AuthenticateResult asyncVariable0 = await authenticationManagerOrThrow.AuthenticateAsync(this._authenticationType);
    if (asyncVariable0 != null)
    {
        IIdentity identity = asyncVariable0.Identity;
        if (identity != null)
        {
            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        }
    }
}
```

So I commented the filter out and it worked :)